# Publish a .Net Core projekt to web, with domain and 1 SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, publish

As the title says.

I've never published a .Net core web app alone.

So I don't know how to do it. What hosting service to look for.
What pricing is reasonable and what company that provides the best services.

Then also how to run my web app on their servers.

Is it just drag and drop my project into the web folder?
How is it done?

Can anyone be very kind and write me an ordered bullet list with steps on how to publish it?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: I use SQL on this project, and if there is something special you need to do to publish with the SQL database

Comment: The published application is there an installed version of SQL Server on the PC?  Are you connecting to a local database or a remote database?  SQL Server can have different instance names and the connection string uses the instance name.  So the installation may require manual operations if you are using a local database.

Comment: Local database, I haven't done anything to the project yet. I just finished it.

Comment: Read my response again I updated it with more questions.

Comment: Yeah the connection string is my pc name